# Java: output one dimensional array as a multi-dimensional array String

Tags: java, arrays, string, format

Bassicaly the data that I get from another tool is this:

1. the one dimension array with all String elements
2. an array of integers representing the number of dimensions for the above array and the size of each dimension.

I need to make a code that will print to a file the array as a multi Dimensional Array.

For Example I get:

```
Integer[] dimensions = dimensions(array);// let us consider it being {2,3}
```

and an one dimensional array with 6 string.
  {a,b,c,d,e,f}
I need to output like this:

```
{
   {
    a,
    b,
    c,
   }
   {
    d,
    e,
    f,
   }
}
```

My attempt was this so far:

```
private String brackets(Integer[] dimensions, String[] array)
{

    for (int j = dimensions.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while (i < array.length - 1)
        {
            if (k == dimensions[j] - 1)
            {
                array[i] = array[i] + "}\n";
                k = 0;
            }
            if (k == 0)
                array[i] = "{\n" + array[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

Dose someone have any better alternative ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the input and the resulting output?

Comment: The current ouptup is (yes I generate C code with Java):
const u16 nc_fid_FID_2D_3_2[3][2] = [{
{
 FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_0, {
 FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_1}
, {
{
 FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_0}
}
, {
 FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_1}
, {
{
 FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_0}
}
,  FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_1];

The input is an array of 6 strings: {FiMConf_FiMFID_FID_2D_3_2_0, ....

Comment: Instead of posting that in the comments, please edit it into your question

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is using integer-division and modulo based on the size of the inner arrays (`3` in your case). For example:

```
private String[][] brackets(Integer[] dimensions, String[] array){
  int arrayLength = array.length;
  int rows = dimensions[0];
  int columns = dimensions[1];

  String[][] result = new String[rows][columns];
  for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    result[i / columns][i % columns] = array[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVBBasMwELznFYuh4BBXTdtjmkOPhfbU3owPiq24m9hSkNYJIfjt7lqWnbTQwyKGnRnN7E4e5f2u2HddXknn4EOivswADs2mwhwcSeLnaLCAmlfxJ1nUZZqBnPc08AKoYQ1anTyI5yu/GJnMtco1FTGnFhsr870iF/f0N02qVDbNLk/Jc5t4i1F2iWSURBuenKfgUTzbqB3tz45ULUxD4sAKinfcRDSElXi1Vp6dKJQ6fJnBLx4izL24nfUFLR4lqduYU7YpFxRYK@3QaJfAtXrvH@rzzwN@V7qkb@7okag8XE0ca06Ol1e/dJldt7mpmlr/ITwGwr/XvDlXb5@lwSbotsbGvTmulyvAl1@5ABeL0ACCYYrwMAbJGNxNYCyVYnBuZ4OMGquDerhr23U/)

The loop iterations will put the items at the 2D indices:
- `i=0`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[0][0] = "a"`
- `i=1`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[0][1] = "b"`
- `i=2`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[0][2] = "c"`
- `i=3`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[1][0] = "d"`
- `i=4`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[1][1] = "e"`
- `i=5`: `[i/3][i%3]` will be `[1][2] = "f"`

---

As for putting everything at new-lines in the format you've provided, I would create a new method to convert a String-matrix into this output:

```
private String prettyPrint(String[][] matrix){
  String result = "{\n";
  for(String[] array : matrix){
    result += " {\n";
    for(String item : array)
      result += "  " + item + ",\n";
    result += " }\n";
  }
  result += "}";
  return result;
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVLdaoMwFL7vUxyEgUXn/u7W9QEGGwx26bxINe3SmliS2K6Iz@6OMcY4VvAQj9@P5zu6Jydyuy8OXZeXRCl4J0w0C4BjvSlZDkoTjcepYgVwhMJPLZnYpRmQZU8DIwAOaxD0bJpwuTLAyESupKouNXJ4spEkP1Ctwp7@KjTdUZlmzWP81MbGYpQ1AQniYIOVYxVYFGsbtKP9RWnKk6rWyREVOuR4Uq0vH6YbXrk05HbRB5LsRDT1x3KzuDmgYJwKxSqhYpiiSkkuNi56D/0bFTv9jZlMl5SmXTmOrM4Kwckvvc8mNK/Kmos/hAdLuLo9bz29fZZaG6vbVjLszdn6fgXsZTYXsCiyCcAapgzuxkEybG5cM4ZKmXVuF4NM11JY9ZW9gv8NvAyc4P2PncBSXa6g@RLBlGG@d3iei8fxIUIhTEpfCwx/DRQOH87CcyFe0UCLIIg9F5/UuufjBhzWWuCfpbRd9ws)

Comment: I do not think it is usefull   I need to declare a multi dimensional array in java with a run time determined number of dimensions.

Comment: @SMarius If you mean the `2` is known instead of the `3` in `[2][3]`, I've made an edit to my answer.

Comment: @SMarius I re-read your question, and I now see you have the `dimensions` `{2,3}` as input. In that case it's much easier. I've edited my answer again, this time it should be more helpful.

Comment: Yes... My mistake, But I can also get as an input something like this: {2,3,4...}, I do not know how many elements Integer[] dimensions has. I found  some mistakes in my code that I posted in the question, unfortunaly the tool takes a lot to run.

Comment: @SMarius I've also added a part about pretty-printing it in the format you've stated. As for the dimensions allowing `{2,3,4,...}` I'm a bit confused what the expected output would become.. :S

Answer (score 0):

You could modify Array.toString(oneDArr[])  according to your needs:
For  instance:

```
   public static String printArray(String[] a) {
        if (a == null)
            return "null";
        int iMax = a.length - 1;
        if (iMax == -1)
            return "{}";

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append('{').append("\n");
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            b.append("  ").append(a[i]);
            if (i == iMax)
                return b.append("\n").append(" }").toString();
            b.append(", ").append("\n");
        }
    }
```

Then, call it and passing one dimensional rows in a loop:

```
        String str[][] = {{"a","b","c"},{"d","e","f"},{"g","h","i"}};
        System.out.println("{");
        for (int i=0; i< nrow; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + Test.printArray(str[i]));
        }
        System.out.println("}");
```

Should give:

```
{
 {
  a, 
  b, 
  c
 }
 {
  d, 
  e, 
  f
 }
 {
  g, 
  h, 
  i
 }
}
```